# writing in arduino with Solid principles

Tags: c++, solid-principles

I am a C programmer and I am new in cpp.for some understandable reason i want to write my program in [S.O.L.I.D](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) way

I want to write a program in c++ in Arduino with OOP.

there are classA , classB ,ClassC and classD.

- classA have to get data from serial port and give an array of bytes
  to classB.
- ClassB do some process and give another array of bytes to classC
- classC make this array into a defined format it to propper
  output. e.g json
- classD take this output and send it via mqtt

my problems are

1. how can I program classA that if I change SerialPort to SPI or other peripheral just by changing a parameter?(Objects or entities should be open for extension, but closed for modification)
2. how these class communicate with each other that if in future  instead of json in classC I choose xml without modifying other class I can extend classC?

sorry for bad English If I am not clear ask in comment

Answer (score 0):

**Embedded programming and OOP are not the best friends, especially in a very limited system like Arduino.** The answer to both questions in classic OOP is polymorphism (with virtual functions). You can create an interface for `classA` and implement getting data in different ways in every derived class.

```
class DataGatherer {
public:
    virtual char* getData() = 0;
    virtual ~IClassA () = default;
};

class SerialPortDataGatherer: public DataGatherer {
public:
    char* getData() override { 
        //any code here
    }
};
```

For less resource-expensive solution you can pretty easily do mapping of parameter to a function (e.g. with a simple `switch-case` statement), if the functions will have common format (like they return array of data or whatever you actually need)

```
enum DataSources {
    SerialPort,
    SPI
}

char* getDataFromSerialPort() {
// logic here
}

char* getDataFromSPI() {
// logic here
}

char* getData(DataSources source) {
    switch(source) {
    case SerialPort:
        return getDataFromSerialPort();
    case SPI:
        return getDataFromSPI();
}
```

---

Note that the first version will likely require a switch-case at some point as well (where you make the decision which input type you should use).

Comment: I think It is possible to write solid in Arduino. I just want to find an example to motivate myself and get Idea. creating Interface is crucial for extending a class and I will use it. but your second way is C way of programming and against S.O.L.I.D. If in future I want to extend communication like I2C I must modify the class